# C - strtod seems to add Digits

Tags: c, file, io, double, strtod

I got a Problem with my `strtod()` it seems to add some digits. I'm reading

```
2\t5241021356985.0302\t9.09\t825.45
```

from a File And after skipping the integer `2` I get the following output

```
output: 5241021356985.030273  9 .090000
```

Here is my Code

```
char *input_string = (char*) calloc(filesize, sizeof (char*));
char *output_string = (char*) calloc(filesize, sizeof (char*));
char *input_end;
fgets(input_string, filesize, infile);
input_end = input_string;
int size_to_read = (int) strtof(input_string, &input_end);
char *temp_string=(char*)calloc(70,sizeof(char*)); // max double value
double temp = 0;
++input_string;
for (int i = 0; i < size_to_read; ++i) {
   temp = strtod(input_string, &input_end);
   sprintf(temp_string, "%lf\t", temp);
   strcat(output_string, temp_string);
   input_string = input_end;
   ++input_string;
}
strcat(output_string, "\0");
printf("output: %s\n", output_string);
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Looks like [float imprecision](http://floating-point-gui.de/) thing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, type `double` has about 16-17 decimal digits worth of precision.
Now, that's not some number of digits past the decimal point -- that's the total number of significant digits, period.  (That's why it's called *floating* point.)

So it's no coincidence that the number you read in, and the number you printed back out, differ after about the 17th digit:

```
 input: 5241021356985.0302
output: 5241021356985.030273
digits: 1234567890123 4567890
                 1          2
```